# Extracting audio from a video file using VLC

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, conversion, video-conversion, audio-conversion

I am trying to extract audio from a given .mp4 file to .mp3 format. In Media>>Convert/Save, I have made setting as showed in images attached.

Now my problem is: I only get *.ts format as output and the output does not run properly.

Any suggestions? Where I am wrong?

Link for Images: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5UInL1OsMmQaXk3NFZwZVlJaXc&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is something wrong with VLC. I suggest you to use another way to extract audio from video file, I often use Audio Extractor to extract mp3 from any video files.

Comment: What makes you conclude that the problem is with VLC rather than, say, the video file?